# Prove that if $f$ is non decreasing then $f' \ge 0$, using the definition of a limit

Tags: limits, solution-verification

So assuming $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, I'm trying to prove that if $f$ is monotone increasing (non decreasing) then is it true that $f'  \ge 0$.

- $f' = \lim _{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$

To preface this, I'm quite confident in my approach to this proof but I'm not $100$% sure what happens to my proof as $h$ approach $0$, this is testing my understanding of limits. I start my splitting up the proof into 2 cases, when $h$ approaches $0$ from the left hand side and the right hand side.

Case 1:

If $h\to 0^-$ then:

- $\lim _{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \ge 0$

because

- $f(a+h) \le f(a)$ $ \to$ $f(a+h) - f(a) \le 0$ and $h <0$

Case 2:

Similarly, if $h\to 0^+$ then:

- $\lim _{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} \ge 0$

because

- $f(a+h) \ge f(a)$ $ \to$ $f(a+h) - f(a) \ge 0$ and $h >0$

And since $f' = \lim _{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} = \lim _{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} = \lim _{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$, we have $f' \ge 0$ as required if $f$ is non decreasing.

To my understanding, $h$ never actually approaches 0 but instead it gets extremely close, and this actually makes sense since if $h$ actually got to $0$, the definition of a limit wouldn't be defined. Is my proof sound?

Comment: In each case, you have a limit of purely non-negative terms, so....  Are you fine with that implying the limit is non-negative?

Comment: @Randall I thought in the first case, the numerator was non-positive? Which when paired with the negative denominator $h$, this meant the fraction was non negative

Comment: Right, which is what I said.

Comment: @Randall Oh yes, and that means in both cases it is non-negative which means $f'$ is non-negative, so my proof is valid?